# How to query all key vaults by tenant (in Azure)?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-sdk

In the interest of avoiding duplicate names for various resources (like key vaults) in Azure, I want to be able to query across all subscriptions in our tenant to see the names already "taken".  e.g., is there already a key vault named `usw2-mkt-kv-001` in one of our subscriptions?

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/vaults/listbysubscription) shows how to query all key vaults by subscription, but what about across all subscriptions?  Or all services (including RGs, Storage accounts, key vaults, vms, etc.) across all subscriptions in our tenant - is there a way to query that?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can (now) use the Azure resource graph to do this directly.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/samples/starter

```
search-azgraph -query 'Resources | where type == "microsoft.keyvault/vaults"'
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to do that, these resources related REST APIs are all based subscription, it means you should specify a subscription id.

Your option is to use [`Subscriptions - List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/list) to list the subscriptions and loop specific REST APIs to query the keyvaults/other resources, make sure the user/service principal you used to get the token has an [RBAC role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/tutorial-role-assignments-user-powershell) in the subscriptions.