# Query for all deleted KeyVaults in tenant?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

We keep getting an VaultAlreadyExists error, but are pretty confident no one else has used the name

We used the [Resource Graph Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63416898/how-to-query-all-key-vaults-by-tenant-in-azure/73820282#73820282) to query for all the keyvaults in our tenant but none with the name came up.

Is there a way to search for all the [deleted key vaults](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/key-vault-recovery?tabs=azure-portal#list-recover-or-purge-a-soft-deleted-key-vault) in a tenant?

Comment: If you want to list the soft deleted key vaults you can achieve it using the az CLI cmdlet `az keyvault list-deleted --subscription {SUBSCRIPTION ID} --resource-type vault` or you can use this [Get Deleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/keyvault/vaults/get-deleted?tabs=HTTP) REST API as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the soft deleted key vaults will have the resource type as `Microsoft.KeyVault/locations/deletedVaults` you cannot pull/fetch them using the azure resource graph explorer.

To achieve this, you can use either Rest API or by using Az CLI/PowerShell cmdlets.

If you want to list the soft deleted key vaults you can achieve it using the az CLI cmdlet

```
   az keyvault list-deleted --subscription {SUBSCRIPTION ID} --resource-type vault
```

Or using this PowerShell cmdlet.

```
Get-AzKeyVault -InRemovedState
```

Alternatively, you can use the Azure Management REST API [Vaults Get deleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/keyvault/vaults/get-deleted?tabs=HTTP).

**Updated Answer**:

If you have more than one subscription, then you need to create a script using either of the above shared cmdlets.
I have created a sample PowerShell script for your reference.

```
Connect-AzAccount
$subslist= Get-AzSubscription | select -Property Id
foreach( $subscription in $subslist){
    Set-AzContext -Subscription $subscription
    Get-AzKeyVault -InRemovedState | select -Property VaultName,ResourceGroupName,Id
}
```

**Note**: Please do make the changes based on your requriment.

Comment: I want to be able to search all of the subscriptions associated with my tenants (there are hundreds) this is for just a specific subscription

Comment: @nastassiar Please refer to my updated answer.